# How do I build this slideshow in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm having an issue passing javascript/css slideshow into ionic.

Ionic doesn't support ".style" in elements. Kindly help out, below is the code

```
<head>
<title>Slideshow</title>
<style>
.slides {display:none;}
</style>
</head>
```

above is hides all media.
below holds media shows and hide

```
<body>

<h2 class="center">Automatic Slideshow</h2>

<div class="content section" style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="slides" src="http://localhost/ads/dashboard/uploads/slides/336d5ebc5436534e61d16e63ddfca3272007281.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="slides" src="http://localhost/ads/dashboard/uploads/slides/03c7c0ace395d80182db07ae2c30f0342007221.png" style="width:100%">
  <video class="slides" playsinline="playsinline" style="width:100%" autoplay muted webkit-playsinline preload="auto">
  <source src="http://localhost/ads/dashboard/uploads/slides/0d43283ccf9d9d6d3a213f5e742425032010261232321.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video class="slides" playsinline="playsinline" style="width:100%" autoplay muted webkit-playsinline preload="auto">
  <source src="http://localhost/ads/dashboard/uploads/slides/838c0f8d4f2ea2a687935d8546d54c302010261232321.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <img class="slides" src="http://localhost/ads/dashboard/uploads/slides/8277e0910d750195b448797616e091ad2007281.png" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

Below is the javascript that changes each media after 10 seconds

```
<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  setTimeout(carousel, 10000); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try with : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides

Answer (score 0):

Make use of

//Put #slides as id for wrapper class containing child div with *ngfor.

```
*ngFor="let img of images" 
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].style.display = "none";  
}
```

//for first time slideIndex must be 1

```
showDivs(slideIndex += n);
enter code here
```

//put all images to null
//Put display block to only slide index

```
x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
```

//for every right arrow button click right/left arrow button click
//The slideshow will start working

At a time only 1 image will be displayed

Comment: my issue is with this x[i].style.display 

ionic does not allow .style 

how can i bypass that

Comment: let floorElements = document.getElementsByClassName("slides") as 
    HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
    floorElements[0].style.display= "none";